# WIFI 6E : Ubuntu 20.04 not able to connect

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi

I have Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz card on ubuntu 20 04, and I am unable to scan the WIFI 6E AP But I am not able to connect to it. Is anybody able to connect to it.

uname -a gives me the following output
`5.15.0-69-generic #76~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 20 15:54:19 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Title says Ubuntu 20 which would be Ubuntu Core 20 but the tag and question say 20.04 please correct.

Comment: Corrected now David

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: I can connect to Wifi 2.4 and 5G. My problem is with Wifi 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5.15 Linux kernel doesn't natively support the latest Intel firmware. Intel's core72 firmware only works with natively with 5.18 and above.

If you want to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS you can try to following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-22.04 
sudo apt-get install git
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
sudo reboot
```

Alternatively you can upgrade the kernel yourself in 20.04 and copy the same files to /lib/firmware

You should note that the 6GHz spectrum is not supported in all countries and Intel has not received regulatory approval for all countries where it is supported.

I do know that latest pnvm and core72 enables supports more countries per this commit:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm?id=20d9516de4cdc041e2aa83009e5b0464b1c3ed81

Intel also dynamically determines the regulatory region using Location Aware Regulatory (LAR) which has been known to make incorrect determinations. To see what region it has assigned, first install the iw package with `sudo apt-get install iw` and then run `iw reg get`. The country you see after phy#0 is the determined country. The output of `iw reg get` will also show you the frequencies that are supported by your device. If you see 6GHz frequencies then your device should have support.

If you see 00: DFS-UNSET after phy#0 then LAR was unable to determine your region. To resolve this see if you can enable 802.11d in your wireless router so that it advertises the region.

If the country detected by LAR is correct but you don't see any 6GHz frequencies in the output then Intel might not have regulatory approval for that region yet.

Comment: Another reason you should probably upgrade to 22.04 if you want to use 6Ghz is that Simultaneous Authentication of Equals (SAE) with SAE Hash-to-Element (H2E) is required for WPA3 Personal in the 6GHz band. H2E is not supported with wpa_supplicant 2.9 which ships with 20.04, but is supported with wpa_supplicant 2.10 which ships with 22.04.

Comment: I tried to upgrade linux firmware. But it is still taking the old file.
loaded firmware version `66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode` . How can I load higher version file like this one?  `iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-79.ucode`

Comment: The firmware versions that iwlwifi will load is based on the version the the Linux kernel.   For Linux kernel 5.15 the highest version that will load is core66. To run higher versions you either need to upgrade your Linux kernel or look into backport-iwlwifi. As commented above I still think upgrading to 22.04 and upgrading your kernel is the best option as you will have other issues is you stay on 20.04.

Comment: I think I understand what needs to be done. I will mark your comment as the answer. Thank you

Comment: I thought wifi 6e was supported since 5.11? I guess the intel wasn't? I also imagine I will need to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.4 to get this working then?