# Jetson Xavier NX + Intel AX210NGW WIFI 6E 6Ghz

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, iwlwifi, wpa-supplicant

my setup:

- Jetson Xavier NX, Jetpack 5.1.1, ubuntu 20.04, linux kernel 5.10
- Intel AX210NGW WIFI 6E 6Ghz
- Router netgear RAXE300 tri-band

situation:
I was able to connect to wifi 6ghz from my laptop running the same Ubuntu 20.04 and the same wifi card.
I then tried to do the same with the Jetson, I was able to follow all the tutorials with the expected results until at the end where I'm unable to see the 6ghz network from the Jetson.
I’m able to connect to 5ghz and 2.4ghz networks from the jetson with the same wifi card, just don't see 6ghz.

software limitations:
I'm unable to upgrade the linux version or firmware due to the jetpack version being already the latest.
I'm aware wifi 6ghz is plug and play with ubuntu 22, but I'm unable to install it.

software modifications i've made:

- upgraded wpa-supplicant from 2.9 to 2.10, to enable 6ghz band
- upgraded linux wifi band registry to latest available (2023-05-03), to enable 6ghz band
- disabled Network Manager, to avoid conflict with wpa_supplicant

Tutorials followed to do so:

- [raspberry wifi 6ghz tutorial](https://dev.to/wataniguchi/how-to-build-a-6ghz-wifi-client-with-a-raspberry-pi-and-netgear-a8000-47ok)
- [ubuntu wifi 6ghz tutorial](https://medium.com/@barry_wu.me/how-to-connect-wi-fi-6e-ap-over-the-6-ghz-band-with-ubuntu-21-04-2a0b4f071ac2)
- [disabling of Network Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091653/how-do-i-disable-network-manager-permanently)
- [how to use wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)

Comment: What OS/release are you using?  Your details imply a non-Ubuntu system (something Ubuntu based that includes Debian too as you mention only a Debian kernel). The Jetson Xavier NX Developer kit is **not** Ubuntu, just Ubuntu based, but not on-topic here. Ubuntu 20.04 uses 5.4 or 5.15 kernels!  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Please see: "The 5.15 Linux kernel doesn't natively support the latest Intel firmware. Intel's core72 firmware only works with natively with 5.18 and above." Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460453/wifi-6e-ubuntu-20-04-not-able-to-connect  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc tahnks,

Comment: @chili555 the situation is apparently more convoluted. Wifi works in 511 and 510 but bluetooth breaks, i don't need it so i don't care, but they later disabled until the issue was resolved in 518. At least that's my understanding from what I've read online.